# How can I navigate the user to a Blazor page from MauiAppCompatActivity in MAUI Blazor?

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui, maui-blazor

I'm developing an MAUI Blazor application.

I want to make an `intent filter` so that I can pick zip files outside of my app and when the user selects `open in another app` can select my app.

When a user comes to my app I should navigate him to a specific Blazor page.

I created a MauiAppCompatActivity and overridden the OnCreate method.

I debugged and see that the Intent class was filled by the correct value.

I want to navigate the user to a Blazor page but I get the following error in these two methods: `OnCreate` and `OnResume`.

Error: `System.InvalidOperationException: ''WebViewNavigationManager' has not been initialized.'`

[image]

How can I navigate the user to a Blazor page in this Scenario?
Generally, is it the correct way for *handling the intent filter* in **`MAUI Blazor`**?

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Functionland.FxFiles.Client.App.Platforms.Android;

[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    DataHost = "*",
    DataSchemes = new[] { "file", "content" },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.ActionView, Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataMimeTypes = new[] { "application/zip" })]
public class ZipViewActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //var fileUrl = this.Intent?.DataString;

        //TODO: pass fileUrl parameter to MyDevice page.
        var navigation = MauiApplication.Current.Services.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
        navigation.NavigateTo("/MyDevice");
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        var navigation = MauiApplication.Current.Services.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
        navigation.NavigateTo("/MyDevice");
    }

}
```

Comment: [I have not used Blazor.] A possible workaround (if no one has a better answer): You could set some static to the information describing where to go, then launch Maui to a simple page (no Blazor). In that page's OnAppearing, have it read that static, navigate as desired. This should ensure that everything is initialized first.

Comment: On Android, both Xamarin and MAUI use a single activity that initializes the MAUI/Xamarin app. If a separate activity is launched, like when the zip file is opened, then this initialization never happens.

Comment: Have you got the answer? @Hamed aHajiloo

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this:

In Main.razor:

```
@code {
    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        var intentPath = Microsoft.Maui.Storage.Preferences.Get("intentPath", string.Empty);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(intentPath))
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo(intentPath);
        }
    }
}
```

In IntentFilter.cs:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
 {
     base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
     HandleIntent(Intent);
 }

 protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
 {
     base.OnNewIntent(intent);

     HandleIntent(intent);
 }

 private void HandleIntent(Intent intent)
 {
     if (intent?.Data != null)
     {
         var data = intent.Data;

         // Xử lý dữ liệu từ Intent ở đây
         var url = data.ToString();

       
         // Lưu trữ đường dẫn yêu cầu để sử dụng trong Main.razor
         Preferences.Set("intentPath", url );
             StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
     }
 }
```

`StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));` will run Main.razor in C# .net maui.